# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5ff31283882e09367cf428ce\n" at path "_id" for model "Posts"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Everything works fine but I have the above-mentioned error while deleting something with id in mongoose. I'm looking for a solution for last 3 days :( but nothing works for me.

```
// Delete a quote
router.delete("/delete/:id", async (req, res) => {
const result = await Post.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, data) => {
if (err) {
  res.status(500).json({
    success: false,
    message: "Sever error.",
  });
} else {
  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    message: "Post Deleted",
    result,
  });
}
});

 res.json(result);
});
```

And my post schema:

```
const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
 },
 desc: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
},
createdAt: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Posts", PostSchema);
```

Comment: You seem to be using both the `async-await` syntax and the callback function. Stick to using only one, preferrably `async-await`.

Comment: i have changed to this simple callback but still same. router.delete("/delete/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Post.findByIdAndDelete({ _id: req.params.id });

 res.json(result);
});

Comment: How are you testing this? Using Postman? The error says the id is not correct/valid. You need to make sure you are passing the right id. It's not clear from your code what's going wrong. We need more related details/code.

Comment: Also, you don't need the last `res.json()` as you are returning a response from the callback function. Finally, `data` is probably the thing you need to return in your `res.json` inside the caallback, and not the result.